# Arranging Woocommerce Variable Product Data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am designing Woocommerce single product page,
I have designed product page for simple product
now I am designing for variable product for that I have created this function
to arrange "Choose variation" selection and "Add to cart" button

```
function filter_grouped_cart(){
   global $post;
   if( function_exists('get_product') ){
       $product = get_product( $post->ID );
       if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 
                    'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 
                    'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 45 );

            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 
                    'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 
                    'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 60 );
        }
    }
}
```

I used conditional logic because without it my simple product page show nothing.
This code is working fine but I have these actions and their priority

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 
        'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
        'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
        'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 
        'woocommerce_template_single_title', 30 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 
        'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 
        'the_content', 40 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
        'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 
        'woocommerce_template_single_price', 50 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
        'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 
        'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 60 );
```

I want "Choose Option" selection before price i.e.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 
        'woocommerce_template_single_price', 50 );
```

Its priority is 50
so i have added priority 45 for

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 
        'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 45 );
```

But still woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart is showing below
`woocommerce_template_single_price`[image]
In the above picture if I have 45-50-60 then 60 and 50 will come in single line, and 45 above 50, that is my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried you code but it broke the structure of the page for me here.

Then ultimately it lead me to research through the hooks and tried some permutation and combination which resulted in this code.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 19 );
```

Hope that works for you. Have not added any conditional logic here to restrict it from getting applied on other types of products(I think that you can handle very well).

[image]

Comment: Yes, This Solved the issue, sorry for late reply.